# Ghidra does not display whole strings

Tags: ghidra

It's pretty annoying. I think I might have changed some setting somewhere.

[image: Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about. See all those "..." ?]

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about. See all those "..." ?

How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to edit the field width.

First, click the "Edit the Listing fields" button:

[image: Edit the Listing fields]

Then, drag the "Field Name" border to the right until the text is fully displayed:

[image: Field width]

Comment: Welp, that was rather simple.
Thank you.

Comment: Some string values are still too long for this to work, is there any alternative to this solution?